# How to build an AlertRow with Eureka for which the type is a custom object

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Is it possible to have an `AlertRow` with the `Eureka` library for which the type is a custom object?

So for example, instead of having:

```
<<< AlertRow<String>("categoryTag") {
        $0.title = "Category"
        $0.optionTitle = "Select a category"
        $0.options = ["Category 1", "Category 2"]
        $0.value = "Category 1"
    }
```

Is it possible to have:

```
<<< AlertRow<Category>("tag1") {
        $0.title = "AlertRow"
        $0.optionTitle = "Select Category"
        $0.options = [category1, category2]
        $0.value = category1
    }
```

Category being a standard class.

This way I could display the category name in the `AlertRow` and retrieve the category ID when a category is selected.

Is it something that can be implemented with `Eureka`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AlertRow is defined like this:

`public final class AlertRow<T: Equatable>: _AlertRow<T>, RowType`

So you can define it with any object that conforms `Equatable`.

Additionally with `$0.displayValueFor` you can customize the text that will be displayed as the alert row options.

Comment: Hi, I have the same need. Do you have any sample class? Appreciate it so much